# Rush Hour solver running into infinite loop any non-trivial puzzle

Tags: java

So I'm writing a Rush Hour solver in Java, which is meant to be able to solve the configurations [here](http://cs.ulb.ac.be/~fservais/rushhour/index.php?window_size=20&offset=0). However, even the simplest puzzle from that page results in the solver running infinitely and eventually running out of memory. I'm using a breadth first search to work my way through all possible moves arising from each board state (using a HashSet to ensure I'm not repeating myself), and mapping each state to the move that got it there so I can backtrack through them later.

The thing is, I've tried it with more trivial puzzles that I've come up with myself, and it's able to solve them (albeit slowly).

Is there anything blatantly wrong with how I'm approaching this problem? I can put up some code from the relevant classes as well if I need to, but I've tested them pretty thoroughly and I'm pretty sure the problem lies somewhere in the code below. My gut says it's something to do with the HashSet and making sure I'm not repeating myself (since the Queue's size regularly reaches the hundred thousands).

Any suggestions?

```
    // Start at the original configuration
    queue.add(originalBoard);

    // We add this to our map, but getting here did not require a move, so we use
    // a dummy move as a placeholder move
    previous.put(originalBoard, new Move(-1, -1, "up"));

    // Breadth first search through all possible configurations
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        // Dequeue next board and make sure it is unique
        Board currentBoard = queue.poll();
        if (currentBoard == null)           continue;
        if (seen.contains(currentBoard))    continue;
        seen.add(currentBoard);

        // Check if we've won
        if (currentBoard.hasWon()) {
            System.out.println("We won!");
            currentBoard.renderBoard();
            return solved(currentBoard);
        }

        // Get a list of all possible moves for the current board state
        ArrayList<Move> possibleMoves = currentBoard.allPossibleMoves();

        // Check if one of these moves is the winning move
        for (Move move : possibleMoves) {
            Board newBoard = move.execute(currentBoard);

            // We don't need to enqueue boards we've already seen
            if (seen.contains(newBoard))   continue;
            queue.add(newBoard);

            // Map this board to the move that got it there
            previous.put(newBoard, move);
        }
    }
```

As requested, here are my initialisations of the HashSet (they're class level variables):

```
private static HashSet<Board> seen = new HashSet<>();
```

And my Board.equals() method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object b) {
    Board otherBoard = (Board) b;
    boolean equal = false;
    if (this.M == otherBoard.getM() && this.N == otherBoard.getN()) {
        equal = true;

        // Each board has an ArrayList of Car objects, and boards are only
        // considered equal if they contain the exact same cars
        for (Car car : this.cars) {
            if (otherBoard.getCar(car.getPosition()) == null) {
                equal = false;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(equal);
    return equal;
}
```

Comment: Please add the initializations of `queue` and `seen`, and the implementations of `Board.hashCode()` and `Board.equals()`. Those are my top suspects for accidental inefficiencies.

Comment: @Douglas will do, although I don't have an implementation of Board.hashCode()...

Comment: Ye it's either what Douglas wrote, or those methods we can't see do something unexpected - move.execute()/currentBoard.allPossibleMoves()/currentBoard.hasWon(). Well, you are using map here so you should definitely implement hashCode, do that. Do that for Move class aswell, both equals and hashcode.

Comment: You put `seen` twice, where's `queue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement `Board.hashCode()` to override the default `Object`-based version, in such a way that, per its contract, any two equal `Board` objects have the same hash code. If you do not, then your `seen` set does not in fact accomplish anything at all for you.

On another issue, I suspect that the way you're checking the boards' cars is not fully correct. If it works the way I think it does, it would consider these two boards to be equal:
`.` = empty space
`*` = part of a car

```
......
.**.*.
....*.
.*....
.*.**.
......

......
.*..**
.*....
......
.**.*.
....*.
```

Comment: I implemented a hashCode function for both the Car and Board objects and it works! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I don't think that's the case, since the cars have X and Y coordinates that are compared in the Car.equals() method?

Comment: @WimKeir The `Car.equals()` method that `Board.equals()` never invokes? Unless `getCar()` works by checking it. Anyway, the difference in my sample boards here is in orientation. Does `Car.equals()` check that as well? Also, you still haven't shown `queue`'s initialization.